# How to avoid using Backspace character with push_back?

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks

I'm making a software as an ATM, so when the user try to enter the password the user only sees `*******`, but when trying to delete it doesn't delete a character. It just adds a new one. Here's my code:

```
string password2 = "";

cout << "PASSWORD: ";

ch = _getch(); 
while(ch != 13) //character 13 is enter
{
   password2.push_back(ch);
   cout << '*';
   ch = _getch();
}
```

And also, I try to use `pop_back();` but it doesn't work either. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I think perhaps I shall not bank with you! You should use the documentation for language features that you use.

Comment: If character 13 is enter, character 8 is backspace. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, it's Backspace character.

Comment: Well Sam DeHaan, I've used it, and I have problems with ASCII values. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Is your issue erasing the '*' that were printed out or filtering out non-printing characters (hint:  `std::isprint`)?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything special with a backspace character.  It just appends it to the string and prints another '*'.  Show us what you've tried.

Comment: The problem is when the user try to delete a string. If the user push the Backspace character, instead of deleting a string, it adds a new character.

Comment: Where's the code to delete a character when the user hits backspace? Are you expecting it to happen by magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a little magic and created this:
I must admit, I don't like the style... But it "works" !

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <conio.h>

bool verify_pass(const std::string& pass)
{
    std::string input = "";
    char ch = '0';
    while(true)
    {
        ch = getch();
        if(ch == '\b')
        {
            if(input.size() > 0)
            {
                input.erase(input.begin() + input.size() - 1);  // erase last char
                std::cout << "\b \b";
            }
        }
        else if(ch != '\r\n' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r')
        {
            input += ch;
            std::cout << '*';
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return input == pass;
}

int main()
{
    std::string insecurePass = "1234";
    std::cout << "Enter Password: ";

    if(verify_pass(insecurePass))
        std::cout << "\nCorrect!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\nFalse!\n";

}
```

By the way, you can use the vector like I used the string, but use push_back instead of += and pop_back() should work too instead of my method with erase.